# rails 5 webpack 4 handling css files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a rails 5 app with webpacker. I am trying to use webpack to both bundle my css files and my js files. 
In my javascripts/packs, I have both an application.js and application.scss files. I added bootstrap as dependencies to my package.json and am now trying to import both bootstrap css and js into my rails app. in application.js I have :

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
import 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
```

In application.scss I have :

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';
```

I cant figure out how to import both scss and js at the same time. In application.html.erb I have both

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

However it's ever the js or the css that is loaded but never both !

I guess there's a problem in the way webpack is configured but I cant figure it out. How do I configure webpack correctly to work with my rails 5 app and bundle both my css and js correctly.

Here's a link to the project :

https://github.com/davidgeismar/Visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading webpacker stylesheet to your Rails application first you should remove app/javascript/packs/application.scss file. Because webpacker separate the stylesheet code with same js file name with stylesheet extensions.

Example - Your webpacker main js file is - app/javascript/packs/application.js and you should import all css and js files inside. So you don't need keep app/javascript/packs/application.scss file, but webpacker generate an application.css file from extracting the code from application.js.

Here's the modified code from your rails app github repo. First remove the app/javascript/packs/application.scss

```
#app/javascript/packs/application.js
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
import 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
//import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

// Added js code for checking webpacker is working fine or not. 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#content-from-webpacker').innerHTML = '<p class="h1">h1. Bootstrap heading</p><h1 class="display-1">Display 1</h1>'
})
```

Here's view code for loading webpacker.

```
#app/views/layout/application.html.erb

<body>
  <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
  <%= yield %>

  <!-- This id(content-from-webpacker) is used for displaying content from webpacker -->
  <div id="content-from-webpacker"></div>

  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</body>
```

I hope it should work. Also I made this changes to your github repo and send a pull request.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. But I noticed I don't need the stylesheet_pack_tag anymore to load bootstrap css. Should I just get rid of it ? Why do we have this helper in the first place then ?

Comment: @DavidGeismar Ok. I am modifying the answer and remove the bootstrap. I added for demonstrating how stylesheets are working with webpacker.